# Understanding why the solutions of a difference equation are given as infinite vectors

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I am currently being introduced to difference equations by the appendix in my book and I need help clarifying one bit. In particular, it is mentioned to me that for a given difference equation the solutions are given as infinite vectors. My interpretation is that since every number can be re written in polar form, each solution will have a different argument making it an infinite vector. Furthermore, comparing difference equations to differential equations, I assume there is a constant that needs to be found such that to get an answer from which infinitely many more can be "generated" by having different arguments. Here is the extract from the book [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for a (complex-valued) sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, ...)$ that satisfies certain properties, this sequence can indeed be viewed as an "infinite vector" or "infinite dimensional vector." That is, $(a_0, a_1, a_2, ...) \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$. If you only cared about $(a_0, a_1,a_2) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ then you would be looking for a 3-d vector.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Michael. I was only wondering why does it say vectors instead of vector. Is it because there is one particular solution and infinitely many general solutions or something else?

Comment: The text writes "... solutions .. infinite vectors...". If it  referred to a single **solution** then it would be **vector** singular.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Michael . From what I am understanding is that a differential equation has one particular solution and a general one, that is, getting the n-th term in terms of one of the terms with some type of a difference independent of the terms. Then is the logic, each solution has its own (a0,a1,a2,...) and all the "solution" vectors form a vector space?

Comment: There are many solutions, one for each initial condition $(a_0,...,a_{d-1})\in \mathbb{C}^d$. The linear combination of two solutions forms another solution and so the set of all solutions is indeed a vector space.

Comment: Hey @Michael, I posted an answer to my own question so I can mark it as Answered. Can you just check if I have interpreted your thoughts thoroughly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael mentioned, there are infinitely many solutions, each for each initial condition, and for each of these solutions there are series associated with it (a0,...,ad−1). It follows that since addition is associative, the vectors as basis, and the space has closure then the set of vectors of the series of the solutions form a vector space.

Again many thanks to @Micheal

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions $(a_0, a_1, ...)$, one for each initial condition $(a_0, a_1, ..., a_{d-1})$.  I would rather ignore the basis issue and just say that because the difference equation is linear and homogeneous, the linear combination of two solutions is also a solution and so the set of solutions is a vector space. I'm not sure associativity is needed to mention.  You can indeed argue that the $d$ solutions that start with $(1,0,0,...,0)$; $(0,1,0,...,0)$, ..., $(0,0,...,0,1)$ indeed form a basis (linearly independent and span) so the vector space is $d$-dimensional.

Comment: So if you find any other $d$ solutions that are linearly independent, then they also form a basis.  The book chapter seems to be hinting at finding solutions $\{\alpha^0, \alpha^1, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, ...\}$ in the case when we can find $d$ distinct solutions $\alpha$ to the characteristic polynomial.  If you can indeed find $d$ distinct solutions $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_d$, you can show that $\{\alpha_1^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, $\{\alpha_2^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, ..., $\{\alpha_d^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Are you really Kanye West?

Comment: @Michael Yes. I decided I am done with beeing the best music producer of all time and I have moved on to study undergrad math and Kim, since she is not as smart, has moved on to study biology.